# Component doesn't inherit service from superclass in Angular 2.4.7

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

In Angular 2.4.4, inheriting from a superclass component worked:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent-component',
    templateUrl: 'parent-component.html',
})
export class ParentComponent {
    constructor(private service:MyService) {
        console.log("Service:", service);
    }
} 

@Component({
   selector: 'child-component',
    templateUrl: 'child-component.html',
})
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {
}
```

However, in Angular 2.4.7, the service now is undefined when instantiating `<child-component>`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Where did you provide `MyService`?

Comment: In the app module

Comment: I see, it's not about parent in child, it's about superclass and subclass.